# Summer 20 Release Guest Site - allow create custom object

Tags: force.com-sites, security, summer20

We have a force.com site that has numerous VF pages to create a custom object. The Summer 20 release report says that we need to / will be forced to shut down access. I see that one can create sharing rules to read a specific object, but how can we enable the site user to CREATE objects?

Comment: This site has some good information as well:
https://www.learncommunitycloud.com/s/article/Guest-User-Record-Access-Development-Best-Practices

Comment: Create objects or records?  Also, there was a workaround to use a `web service` method in order to do certain DML that were otherwise impossible from a public site VF page, but not sure if it's relevant with the recent updates

Comment: Records for custom objects, thanks. I'll have a look at web services.

Answer (score 1):

Guest user security updates do NOT affect creating records - except in scenarios where they're creating records tied to other records that they don't have access to or doing subsequent updates in automation that follows the creation of the record.